# Site interagindo com o sistema local

Tags: linux, aplicação-web

Tenho uma aplicação WEB rodando num servidor interno, a ser acessada unicamente via rede interna, através de browser em máquinas Ubuntu.

A minha real necessidade é em determinado momento enviar um sinal às portas (seja paralela, serial ou USB) dos computadores que estejam acessando a aplicação através do browser, controlado por esta aplicação WEB. Penso em fazer isso enviando comandos diretamente do browser ao Linux, para executar as aplicações responsáveis por esta interação com o hardware.

Caso não haja uma forma direta de fazer isso, eu poderia criar uma aplicação que ficasse lendo um banco de dados ou um arquivo TXT gerado pela aplicação WEB e quando houvesse alteração, tomasse as devidas providências em nível de hardware.

Qual seria a melhor forma de eu resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns browsers implementam mecanismos específicos para acesso ao hardware.

No caso do Chrome, há uma [API para acessar USB](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb) e outros dispositivos. Então você poderia escrever uma extensão para realizar as operações que precisa no hardware.

Com a extensão funcionando e instalada, sua página web pode se comunicar com ela, enviando mensagens, por exemplo, através de [eventos personalizados](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication).

Funciona mais ou menos assim. Se a página precisa acessar o hardware, ele dispara um determinado evento, o qual é capturado pela extensão que, por sua vez, faz o acesso ao hardware via USB e retorna o evento para a página.